# OpenGL ES 3.0 GL_POINTS doesn't render anything

Tags: linux, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

Below is a mininal reproducer:

```
  GL_CHECK(glClearColor(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f));
  GL_CHECK(glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT |
                   GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT));
  GL_CHECK(glUseProgram(this->pp_->shader_program));
  GL_CHECK(glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D));
  GL_CHECK(glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0));
  GL_CHECK(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->particle_->id));
  GLfloat points[] = { 150.f, 150.f, 10.0f, 150.0f, 175.0f, 10.0f };
  GLfloat colors[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
  shader_pass_set_uniform(this->pp_, HASH("mvp"), glm::value_ptr(this->camera_));
  GL_CHECK(glEnableVertexAttribArray(0));
  GL_CHECK(glEnableVertexAttribArray(3));
  GL_CHECK(glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &points[0]));
  GL_CHECK(glVertexAttribPointer(3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &colors[0]));
  GL_CHECK(glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 2));
```

vertex shader:

```
#version 300 es

layout(location = 0) in highp vec3 vertex;
layout(location = 3) in highp vec4 color;

out lowp vec4 vcolor;

uniform mat4 mvp;

void main()
{
   vcolor               = color;
   gl_Position          = mvp * vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
   gl_PointSize         = vertex.z;
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 300 es

uniform sampler2D stexture;
in lowp vec4 vcolor;

layout(location = 0) out lowp vec4 ocolor;

void main()
{ 
    ocolor = texture(stexture, gl_PointCoord) * vcolor;    
}
```

Nothing gets rendered on-screen, my `glxinfo` can be found [in this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kN0XMYyr). When I render the same texture onto a triangle it works.

Here is also the render loop as captured with `apitrace`:

```
250155 glClearColor(red = 0.5, green = 0.5, blue = 0.5, alpha = 1)
250157 glClear(mask = GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
250159 glUseProgram(program = 9)
250161 glEnable(cap = GL_TEXTURE_2D)
250163 glActiveTexture(texture = GL_TEXTURE0)
250165 glBindTexture(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture = 2)
250167 glUniformMatrix4fv(location = 0, count = 1, transpose = GL_FALSE, value = {0.001953125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.002604167, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, -0, 1})
250168 glEnableVertexAttribArray(index = 0)
250170 glEnableVertexAttribArray(index = 3)
250174 glVertexAttribPointer(index = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = GL_FALSE, stride = 0, pointer = blob(24))
250175 glVertexAttribPointer(index = 3, size = 4, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = GL_FALSE, stride = 0, pointer = blob(32))
250176 glDrawArrays(mode = GL_POINTS, first = 0, count = 2)
250178 glXSwapBuffers(dpy = 0x1564010, drawable = 50331661)
```

Comment: The way I read the matrix in the API trace, the points would be outside the clip volume. I don't think a `z` value of 10.0f is within the visible range using that matrix.

Comment: @RetoKoradi The 'z' coordinate is interpreted in the shader as point size.

Comment: @id256 How would I know? I'm not the one asking the question.

Comment: Since this is on Linux, which normally also supports desktop OpenGL: Are you specifically creating an ES 3.0 context? There are some differences in point rendering between OpenGL ES and OpenGL.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Sorry man, my intention was to ask the OP.

Comment: @arul What do you mean by "render the same texture onto a triangle"? glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, ... with some other organization of the position data? And what happens, when you try to render it with GL_LINES?

Comment: @RetoKoradi yes, this is OpenGL ES 3.0 context.

Comment: @id256 yes, I can render `GL_TRIANGLES / GL_TRIANGLE_STRIPS / GL_LINES` just fine. The problem happends when rendering `GL_POINTS`.

Comment: @arul Does it render anything if you use something like `ocolor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);` in the fragment shader?

Comment: @id256 Yes, I can see 1px red dots at the expected locations! The texture is actually transparent at (0, 0) so that's why it probably didn't render anything. But why is the `gl_PointSize` ignored? Btw. I just tried `gl_PointSize         = 30.0f;` but still 1px dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that could mean, that the range of point sizes, that your GLES implementation supports, may be not what you are expecting. You can try something like:

```
GLint range[2];
glGetIntegerv(GL_ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE, range); // for example, (1, 511) in my implementation
```

to check it out. Any implementation guarantees, that `range[1]` is at least `1.0`. The value `gl_PointSize` is getting clamped to the range, so in the worst case you won't be able to set point with size, greater than 1. In this case `gl_PointCoord` seems to evaluate to `(1, 0)` (according to formula from specs) at the only fragment, that is going to be drawn for each point. After the texture's wrap mode come into play, `(1, 0)` may turn into `(0, 0)`, for example if you are using `GL_REPEAT` as the texture's wrap mode. If you'd like to safely draw a point with side, greater than one, you should try using the ordinary way to draw squares (for example using four vertices and `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` or `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` mode).

Comment: I've got (1, 2047), so it should be supported. Any idea besides buggy drivers?

Comment: @arul None yet. And ignoring `gl_PointSize` looks very strange ... Though if the range was (1,1) everything would be pretty explainable.

Comment: @arul Are you using scissor or stencil test?

Comment: @arul Anyway, if it takes a lost of time to figure out the issue, I'd stick to the obvious solution, that I mentioned in the end of my answer.

Comment: Neither of them. I'm reporting the error to NVIDIA. Well, this part of codebase is supposed to handle point clouds and CPU particles, so I really can't make it quads. I want to have +/- megaparticles for GPU particle system. I'll wait some more time then accept your answer, as it helped me to confirm that what I have _should_ work, and also that it _works_ only for single pixel :)

Comment: @arul Ok, good luck. When you find something, could you share your knowledge? ;)